# How can you change the context.fillStyle property from a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the context.fillStyle property inside another function, is it possible ?

```
function init()
{
  context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
  handle = setInterval(draw,10);
}

function draw()
{
  context.clearRect(0,0, 600,400);
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle="gray";
  context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();
  if( x<20 || x>580) dx=-dx;
if( y<20 || y>380) dy=-dy;
x+=dx;
y+=dy;
}
```

and i wanna change the property inside my change function

Comment: So where is your change function?

Comment: If you hardcode it in `draw`, changing it outside is useless. Use variables, accessible by both your functions.

Comment: @Kaiido i have the var context... how can i change it in another function ?

Comment: No you don't get me... I  your `draw` function, the `fillStyle` is hard-coded to the value `"gray"`. So even if you change the context value outside, it will still got set in here to this value. Instead, create a variable, say `var currentColor = "gray"`,  then in `draw` change `..fillStyle = "gray"` to  `..fillStyle = currentColor;` Now you just have to update `currentColor = ...` in your change function.

Comment: it works thank you sir !